# SqlContext Error?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am trying to save a json file to Elasticsearch.
I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError

I am using "spark 2.3.0" and "scala 2.11.6"
please find the code Below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object OrangetoES {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("OrangetoES").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true")
    val sqlc = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlc.read.json("../Orange.json")
    df.saveToEs("orangetoes/people")
  }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

just i have to modifie the ES-Hadoop version from 13 to 20